# Looking for some computable examples of sheaf of total quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is mentioned in Ueno's Algebraic Geometry 3, Chpt 7, Sec 2 without concrete example. It is located at pg 43 right above exactsequence (7.33).

Let $X$ be a scheme and $U=\operatorname{Spec} R\subset X$ open affine. Define $Q(U)=S^{-1}R$ where $S$ is the set of non-zero divisor of $R$. This defines a pre-sheaf over affine open set of $X$. Then I can sheafify it to get $Q$ sheaf of total quotient over $X$. Computing stalks would not be too hard from definition. However, I have significant amount of hard time to even see what is $Q(Spec(R))$ or $Q(U)$ over $U$ affine.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What are non-trivial computable non-integral examples of such $Q$? I am looking for some computable examples to see what kind of sheaf I am dealing with. It is easy to deal with single point or finite number of points. I am looking for examples of at least dimension 1 above.

Comment: Take $X$ to be an integral affine scheme. Then the sheaf is determined by its global sections, which is just the fraction field of the structure sheaf of $X$. For example, if $X= \mathbb{A}^1$, then $Q=k(x)$, the field of rational polynomials in one variable

Comment: @leibnewtz I am not sure whether your statement is true or not. There was an exercise in Ueno's Algebraic Geometry 2 saying $U$ affine open in Noetherian scheme $X$, then $\Gamma(U,Q_X)=Q(\Gamma(U,O_X))$ where $Q(-)$ is the total quotient ring by inverting all non-zero divisors. Somehow the proof involves using noetherian condition.

Comment: @leibnewtz I am looking for non-integral or non-noetherian examples or both non-integral and non-noetherian examples in particular.

Comment: You could try computing the ring of fractions for $k[x_1,...,x_n,...]/(x_1^2)$

Comment: @leibnewtz Certainly global section will have $Q(k[x_1,\dots]/(x_1^2))$ which inverts everything but zero divisors of the form $g(x_2,\dots,x_m)x_1$. However, is there any reason to see whether it has more sections?

Comment: Could you please be more precise: the  section 2 you mention is 39 pages long! And writing "an exercise in Ueno's Algebraic Geometry 2" is even worse: the book has 184 pages :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry for being imprecise. It is pg 43 either right before exact sequence (7.33).

Comment: Thank you for the precise reference, dear user45765.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was not adequate, so here is a clarification. The assignment $U \mapsto Q(U)$ that you describe is not a presheaf for $X$ nonintegral (when we allow ourselves to consider nonaffine $U$). This has something to do with the fact that an arbitrary map of commutative rings does not send nonzero divisors to nonzero divisors in general. Consequently, this object will be fairly complicated. For more information about this, see the paper $\textit{Misconceptions about $K_X$}$ by Kleiman.

When $X$ is integral, the situation is nicer. In this case, it is trivially true that nonzero sections of the structure sheaf restrict to nonzero divisors, so the sheaf that you describe is well-defined, even over nonaffine $U$. When $X$ is affine, the global sections of $Q$ will just be the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}(X)$.

Remark: When $X$ is noetherian, the value of the sheafification of $Q$ at an affine open $U$ being the total ring of fractions of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ has to do with the fact that we are sheafifying. If $X$ is not noetherian, the value of the sheaf on an affine open may be different from that of the presheaf $Q$. For what it's worth, in my limited experience I've never seen anyone use this sheaf for schemes that are not varieties.